# Under what conditions can Vbe exceed 0.7

Tags: switches, bjt

I am simulating a transistor switch in PSPICE. The goal is to switch a load (like a lamp) connected in the collector on and off. Imagine that in the place of the R2 resistor there is this aforementioned load.

[image: schematic]

I understand that the smaller the R1 resistor the deeper in saturation I drive the transistor which is preferable. But how small can R1 be? In simulation I am observing that Vbe can get a lot larger that 0.7 volts and Ib is getting large as well. Is this dangerous? Are there any governing equations for Ib and Vbe in the schematic topology I am using?

Answer (score 1):

The data sheet will usually give a fair idea about this: -

[image]

***Pulse Condition: Pulse Width ≤300μs, Duty Cycle ≤2%.**

As you can see, the base-emitter voltage under extreme base currents can be a maximum of 2.6 volts but typically 1 volts is not unheard of.

> In simulation I am observing that Vbe can get a lot larger that 0.7
>   volts and Ib is getting large as well. Is this dangerous?

0.7 volts is just a convenient value engineers use. I wouldn't recommend getting too close to the limits and if you need to turn on your 2N2222 a bit harder I would recommend using a MOSFET.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. Do you incidentally know any equation governing Ib and Vbe for the switching topology I am using?

Comment: There is the "Ebers-Moll equation" for a bipolar transistor and there is the "shockley diode equation" but these are not going to be that useful in terms of a particular transistor because of the make-up of the actual device. Ditto the "Gummel poon model". All useful in their own way but not very helpful in exact predictions for base-emitter forward characteristics. The data sheet says the values can be anywhere from 0.6 volts to 2.3 volts so manufacturing methods cloak theory unfortunately.

Comment: As a new member I would advise you to take [the small tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand the motives behind helping with questions.